# Updating Total causing infinite loop

Tags: c#

I current have 3 telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput.

The first one is the principal

The First and Second are the disbursals

At the moment I have it set up such that principal = First disbursal + Second disbursal.

I'm trying to have a case such that if I update principal it updates First Disbursal and sets second disbursal to zero. So Principal = DisbursalOne and DisbursalTwo = 0

```
// Pv is principal
private decimal?_pv;
public decimal? Pv { get { return _pv; } set { _pv = value; OnPropertyChanged("Pv"); } }

private decimal? _disbursalOne;
public decimal? DisbursalOne
{
    get
    {
        return _disbursalOne;
    }
    set
    {
        _disbursalOne = value;
        if (_disbursalOne != null)
            DisbursalTotal = _disbursalOne + DisbursalTwo;
        else
        {
            _disbursalOne = 0;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("DisbursalOne");
    }
}
```

Disbursal Two essentially almost identical to Disbursal one so the Code is not necessary.

```
private decimal? _disbursalTotal;
public decimal? DisbursalTotal 
{ 
    get { return _disbursalTotal; } 
    set
    { 
        _disbursalTotal = value;
        if (_disbursalTotal != null) UpdateDisbursalTotal(_disbursalTotal); 
            else UpdateDisbursalTotal(0);
        Pv = _disbursalTotal;
        OnPropertyChanged("DisbursalTotal"); 
    } 
}
```

I apologize for the bad title.

```
// Updates the Total Disbursed Fields on the UI 
public void UpdateDisbursalTotal(decimal? Total)
{
    var cultureInfo       = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;   // You can also hardcode the culture, e.g. var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), but then you lose culture-specific formatting such as decimal point (. or ,) or the position of the currency symbol (before or after)
    var numberFormatInfo  = (NumberFormatInfo)cultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();
    numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "$"; // Replace with "$" or "£" or whatever you need
    Double _total         = (double) Total;
    DisburseString        = _total.ToString("C", numberFormatInfo);
}

private string _disburseString;
public string DisburseString { get { return _disburseString; } set { _disburseString = value; OnPropertyChanged("DisburseString"); } }
```

Comment: What does `UpdateDisbursalTotal` do?

Comment: Updated code* but basically it updates the UI with the value in a currency format

Comment: You have a lot of tightly coupled code here, so it's difficult to figure out the problem. What does `DisburseString` look like? And `Pv`?

Comment: A label on the UI where it's Content is binded to DisbursedString

Comment: But what is `DisburseString`?

Comment: Updated disbursestring, DisbursedString is the total disbursed. Srry I can see where you're confused.

Comment: My advice to you is to put a brake point in your code and look at the call stack. You should be able to see the re-entrant function. At least you should be able to see where the code is being called from that should give you some clue. Your code does not give enough context for a proper answer.

Comment: I agree with @BigT, there's just not enough info here to debug. The code as shown doesn't have any recursion, but it's possible that something outside is causing an update when the `OnPropertyChanged` events happen.

Comment: Also, what you posted wouldn't compile. How can you do this: `Pv = _disbursalTotal;`?

Comment: How Can I not? @DavidG I dont understand what you are asking... Well it won't compile because 20% of the code is missing... DisbursalTwo.... `Disbursal Two essentially almost identical to Disbursal one so the Code is not necessary.`

Comment: `Pv` is an `int` and `_disbursalTotal` is `decimal?`, the compiler would throw an error doing that.

Comment: ahh yes you are correct. Thank you for pointing that out, changes have been made

Comment: It's no good posting incomplete code and us asking for more bit by bit. You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It was a small mistake, I have one variable name Pf, Another Pv. Humans make small copy and paste mistakes :p

Comment: I've now asked for additional information 4 times, a good question has all the information needed to obtain an answer. I shouldn't have to ask at all.

Comment: Alright understandable. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to format your `PropertyChanged` events in the following way, that way if the same value gets set, you don't notify anyone as nothing has actually changed.  If things are relying on your `PropertyChanged` events to update each other, this should break the cycle:

```
private decimal? _disbursalTotal;
public decimal? DisbursalTotal 
{ 
    get { return _disbursalTotal; } 
    set
    { 
        if (value != _disburseTotal) {
            _disbursalTotal = value;
            if (_disbursalTotal != null) UpdateDisbursalTotal(_disbursalTotal); 
                else UpdateDisbursalTotal(0);
            Pv = _disbursalTotal;
            OnPropertyChanged("DisbursalTotal"); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code. My guess is that OnPropertyChanged event also changes a property. You can check if the property is actually changing (or just being set to the same value) before calling OnPropertyChanged.